# When to use cookie store vs redis store for session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

In Rails, the default for storing the `session` is using `cookie_store`.

```
Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

But sometimes, the `session` is stored in a database, like Redis.

```
Application.config.session_store(
  :redis_store,
  servers: config.redis_server,
  key: '_myapp_sessions',
)
```

When should we use the cookie store and when should we use a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you need to store more than **4KB** of data in your session.
- When you need more control over expiring sessions. Here are two examples where you might need this kind of control:

  1. If you make a change to your app that requires new information to be in the session or there is a security breach and you need to expire all sessions so that all users need to sign in again, it is much easier if the sessions live in a database vs needing to change the `secret_key_base` to invalidate `cookie_store` sessions.
  2. A **Maintained Session** is where an attacker keeps a session alive indefinitely. The problem is mentioned here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry If you want to protect against a **Maintained Session** this is easily done using a database by setting a `created_at` attribute on the session and not with a `cookie_store` session because it gets re-created with each request.

Answer (score 0):

If your rails app running on a cluster(multiple servers) environment or session data goes beyond 4KB(cookie store has the limit of 4KB memory) then use Redis or any other database.

Comment: thanks for answering, I understand the 4KB limit but why does running on a cluster mean to use redis for the session data?

Comment: If your app is running on multiple servers behind the load balancer, once you log in to the app session will be created but the next request may not go to the same server(requests served in round robin or any other algorithm), So the user has to login again. To avoid that you need to share the session using some database between the servers

Comment: But sessions exist in Rails regardless of logging in.  In fact, you can use the session to implement a basic login mechanism. Also, with multiple servers, the session cookie is still sent with each request and it has all the information in it already. So not sure why we need to share it between servers.

Comment: The answer was mostly correct but I wish I could downvote the second comment which replies to the first comment.

I can confirm that `cookie_store` works just fine when used with a cluster of servers. As long as they all have the same `secret_key_base` and the session has not timed out, they will all consider it valid.